# If you give a bounty, can you earn it back without counting toward the daily rep limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

I know that the 15 reputation given for answers isn't subject to the daily 200 limit on reputation.  I also know that if you have maxed out reputation for the day, and then you lose reputation by downvoting or being downvoted, you can earn that reputation back until you hit your max for the day (although this doesn't occur retroactively, and I think it should).

Can you also earn back reputation you give in a bounty, or is that treated as totally separate from the reputation you earn or lose in a given day?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the maximum reputation you can ever earn for upvotes in a day is always capped at 200. It doesn’t matter whether you have lost reputation because of starting a bounty, or because people have downvoted you.

So if you spent 100 on a bounty and also gained 200 by upvotes, that's all you could gain from those upvotes, and the order would not matter. You'd still net +100 up for the day.

Comment: please help me @tchrist to increase the bounty I just posted on my newly reopened question:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400197/how-do-i-choose-between-who-or-whom-when-the-subject-pronoun-is-murky   I want to make it 200 points. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Putting a bounty in a question doesn't change the reputation cap, which means that offering 100 of your reputation for a bounty doesn't make your reputation cap for that day 300.

It's the reputation that you gain with bounties offered to you that don't count toward the reputation cap. It means that if you get 100 points through a bounty, that day your reputation change can also reach 300 (not 200 as usual).